# dom is not defined error after transforming jsx to js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I created a jsx file as below

```
  /** @jsx dom */
(function(){
'use strict';

define([
        'jquery',
        'react',
        'react-dom'
    ],

    function($, React, ReactDOM){

        var AppView = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <div>Hello World</div>;
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<AppView />, document.getElementById('dsl-application'));

    });
})();
```

And transformed the jsx to js using below command

```
babel --watch src --out-dir bundle --preset react
```

And the out put file is like below

```
(function () {
'use strict';

define(['jquery', 'react', 'react-dom'], function ($, React, ReactDOM) {

    var AppView = React.createClass({
        displayName: 'AppView',

        render: function () {
            return dom(
                'div',
                null,
                'Hello World'
            );
        }
    });


    ReactDOM.render(dom(AppView, null), document.getElementById('dsl-application'));
});
})();
```

The problem is I got Uncaught ReferenceError: dom is not defined when I run the js file in browser. dom is added after transformation. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any JSX here. Can you explain a bit more which plugin you're expecting will add `dom` after the transformation?

Comment: you are right. I updated the jsx code.

Comment: Why do you have `/** @jsx dom */` in your code?

Comment: Because it's a jsx file. Should I remove it?

Comment: I use jsx every day and never have used that. I would try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: Can I ask how you transform  your jsx to js?

Comment: I use webpack. You just define a webpack config file, run `webpack` in the console, and you're done.

Comment: I removed /** @jsx dom */  and still getting error

Comment: What's your new error?

Comment: @JoshBeam you used to need it for React until version v0.12 (just giving historical context if curious)

Comment: @gabdallah ah I see! Thanks

Comment: I set up wenpack but I am getting React not defined in bundle file. Note that I am using Require. Any clue?

Comment: @JoshBeam I set up webpack but I am getting "React not defined" in bundle file. Code line: module.exports = React;  Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform JSX to JS in browser, you need `browser.js` from `babel`. For a simple example refer to https://github.com/ruanyf/react-demos/blob/master/demo01/index.html

[[UPDATE BASED ON MORE INFO]]

Use the following files and then run `npm install` and `webpack` , then your `index.html` will be ready to be served.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "another",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

main.jsx

```
'use strict'

var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var AppView = require('./component.jsx')

ReactDOM.render(
    <AppView />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

component.jsx

```
'use strict'

var React = require('react')

var AppView = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>)
    }
});

module.exports = AppView
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015']
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not going to transform it in browser. I want to precompile it

Comment: I 'll give it a try and let you know and if it was helpful will definitely accept it as answer. At the moment we changed the approach to meet the deadline. will try it in earliest chance

Answer (score 2):

Run into this same issue with a basic React app.

Turned out that the culprit was in my webpack.config.js. I had:

```js
plugins: [ 
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
        "pragma": "dom" 
    }]
]
```

babel's default pragma is React.createElement (https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/).

The truth is that I had no reason for this option, I had just copy/pasted 
from the link above.

From the docs, I should have imported the 'dom' module that I had
specified and made sure I had babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic installed.

The docs for this plugin are here https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-pragmatic and explain a little bit about pragmas.

I fixed this issue by simply removing the 'pragma' option so I could 
just use the default one ( attached a part of my webpack.config.js to provide more context): -- I am using webpack 2.6.1

```js
...
module: {
    rules: [{
      //a regexp that tells webpack to use the following loaders on all
      //.js and .jsx files
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: ["es2016", "react", "stage-0"],
        plugins: [
          ["transform-react-jsx"]
        ]
      },
      //we definitely don't want babel to transpile all the files in
      //node_modules. That would take a long time.
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },

...
```