# Uncaught ReferenceError: dom is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I set up an environment with Node.js, React and Webpack, but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import "../style/index.less"


class Demo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box">
        {this.props.text}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo text="this is a test" />,
  document.querySelector('.container')
)
```

After Webpack, the generated code is:

> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_react_dom___default.a.render(dom(Demo, {
>     text: "this is a test"
>   }), document.querySelector('.container'));

When I write a HTML file that src this js, it tells me

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dom is not defined

And I also search this dom definition in all files but I cannot find it.

the index.html is very simple:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../build/style/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script src="../build/script/runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="../build/script/vendor.js"></script>
  <script src="../build/script/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the webpack.config.js is as below:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const extractless = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '../style/[name].css',
})

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/script/index.js',
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/script'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/script")
        ],
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: extractless.extract({
          use: [{
              loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
            },
            {
              loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
            },
          ],
          fallback: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings                      
        })

      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractless,
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'runtime']
    })
  ],

}
```

at first I use webpack4 and I get this error, so I switch to webpack3 and the error remains.

Comment: Hi Felix, I don't know much without seeing your index.html.

Couple of things I can think of:

- Did you specify the proper entry file in your webpack.config?
- Do you have an index.html?
- If you check the html output in your console, does it reference your bundled code or does it reference the source files?

Comment: Also: a quick google search gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281619/dom-is-not-defined-error-after-transforming-jsx-to-js). Perhaps this is a duplicate?

Comment: thx a lot, I found the plugin `transform-react-jsx` can resolve this problem

Comment: it use `createElement` instend of `dom`

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)